# Is there a way to specify the order of creation of the columns for an SQL table conception using Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm curently reproducing an old postgresql database with a Django model. The first version of the database had some scripts to compute data to populate the tables.

The data I want to insert in the table are formated as a TSV file : `value1\tvalue2\value3`. They next will be inserted using the SQL command `\copy my_table from 'path/to/my/file.tsv' with null as 'NULL'`.

Because the script define the order of the data in the TSV file, my fields have to be created with the same order in the table. The problem is that Django seems to set the Foreign keys to the end of the table.

This model exemple :

```
class My_table(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=25)
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(....)
    field3 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    field4 = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
```

Can give a table like :

```
  field1 | field3 | field4 | field2  
 --------+--------+--------+--------
```

I want this :

```
  field1 | field2 | field3 | field4  
 --------+--------+--------+--------
```

Is there a way to have this result?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using built-in Django migrations, you can actually re-order the `fields` defined in a migration file to change the order columns are created in the database.

You should have something similar to this:

```
# 0001_initial.py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ....
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(

            # the fields here can be re-ordered
            fields=[
                ('id', ...),
                ('field1', ....),
                ('field2', ....),
                ('field3', ....),
                ('field4', ....),
            ]
        )
    ]
```

You can use `python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001` to print out the SQL that would be executed:

```
CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("id", ....);
```

Note that regardless of field ordering, Django will force "id" to be the first column defined in a table.

Comment: I have to manually modify the django's migration result? It is a complex solution if I have to write a script to execute this intermediary operation. A new step during the first migration  seems to be a difficulty if I have to redeploy the database model... Nothing else known in the module settings or in the models arguments I have missed ?

Comment: In my testing of Django 1.9.1, the order in which the fields are defined is same as the order of columns in my database. What version of Django, and what database are you using?

Comment: I'm curently using Django 1.9.0 and Postgresql 9.3.9 with python 3.4.3

Comment: I would honestly just modify the initial migrations by hand. If you redeploy, you will not be generating new migrations anyway (you'll be re-using the migrations which you modified). If you have hundreds of tables, then you might consider using your old database to generate the schema for the new database, and just run migrations with `--fake-initial` parameter.

Comment: My example wasn't a real code, it was just what I had seen. I've just observed that in my case the problem only happen  with the foreign keys (if they aren't also used as primary keys). They are moved to the end of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look into a Django code and it looks like during make-migration run it first add all normal field followed by one with relations (this way foreign keys field are became last).

So it seems there is no easy solution without modifying Django itself. Thus manual change of `0001_initial.py` looks like the only option.

But the manual change of field order is also not a maintainable option for large number of models. So here is a little hack to set order from Models in automatic way.

Add following to the end of your `0001_initial.py` file and change `db.models` to your models:

```py
# import your models
import db.models as my_models

# Change field order to one in model
for op in Migration.operations:
    if isinstance(op, migrations.CreateModel):
        Model = getattr(my_models, op.name)
        fields = {field_tuple[0]: field_tuple for field_tuple in op.fields}
        new_fields = []
        for field in Model.__dict__:
            if field in fields:
                new_fields.append(fields[field])
        op.fields = new_fields
```

This code change the order in `migrations.CreateModel` based on attributes order from original model.

Still not awesome, but at least there is no need to do it manually. Just add a little code at the end.